# Append new values to JSON property in Python

Tags: python, arrays, json, string

I have a JSON string which I retrieve from my database (MySQL)and I need to add another value to the **daysOff** property in the JSON string.  Once I've appened the new value to the JSON string, I need to update my table with the new value.

I'm new to Python, and I understand strings are immutable, the part I'm having trouble with is traversing through the array to add a new value to the **daysOff** property

This is what I have so far:

```
import mysql.connector as mysqlConnector
import sys
import json
from datetime import date

query = "SELECT option_value FROM my_tbl WHERE option_name='my_holiday_settings'"
    try:
        cur.execute(query)
        myresult = cur.fetchall()
        for x in myresult:
            dictionary = json.loads(*x)
            key = 'daysOff'
            checkKey(dictionary, key)
            print(dict)
            print(dictionary)
            print(type(dictionary))
    except Exception as e:
        print('error:', e)
    finally:
        cur.close()


def checkKey(dict, key):
    if key in dict.keys():
        test_dict = {"name":"test","startDate":"9999-01-01","endDate":"9999-09-09","repeat":"0"}
        dict[key]=test_dict
        print("value updated =", 600)
    else:
        print("Not Exist")
```

This is my JSON

```
{
  "notifications": {
    "whatsAppBusinessID": "None",
    "whatsAppLanguage": "Alien"
  },
  "daysOff": [
    {
      "name": "Xmas",
      "startDate": "2022-01-09",
      "endDate": "2022-01-09",
      "repeat": true
    },
    {
      "name": "Australia Day",
      "startDate": "2022-01-26",
      "endDate": "2022-01-26",
      "repeat": true
    },
    {
      "name": "Good Friday",
      "startDate": "2022-04-15",
      "endDate": "2022-04-15",
      "repeat": true
    },
    {
      "name": "Holy Saturday",
      "startDate": "2022-04-16",
      "endDate": "2022-04-16",
      "repeat": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: From what I see everything should be working. Are there any errors or unwanted behaviour?

Comment: Yes, the error I get is: "error: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not tuple". If I convert to str, I get "error: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Comment: How do you interact with the database?

Comment: How do you mean? I just execute the query in the code above and get the json string from the table and initially store it in value x

Comment: Yes but what package do you use sqlite3 or something else? I need to know what cur.fetchall() returns

Comment: My apologies. I've updated the code to show what packages i'm importing

Comment: cur.fetchall() returns the json string

Comment: I've updated my answer for json string stored in the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cursor.fetchall()
```

returns a list of tuples which means that x in your for loop is a tuple. You can convert tuples to dictionaries using this

```
tuple_as_dict = dict(tuple)
```

---

If store your data as json string you first need to unpack the tuple and the convert it into a string

```
dictionary = json.loads(*tuple)
```

---

```
json.loads(string)
```

also returns a dictionary but takes strings and not tuples as argument

Comment: Thank you, this has got me on the correct path. However, the issue I have now is when I try and insert a new element under the key daysOff, all the previous values are overwritten with the new value.  I've updated the code